# Constantes in asymptotique formulas of consecutif primes

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $q$ be a prime number, and $m$ an even number.

Let $\displaystyle\mathcal{B}_q=\{b \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \, | \, b \wedge {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}=1 \text{ and } b \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)} \}$

Let $I_{q,m}(n)$ denote the number of **consecutif** elements $(b,b+m)$ less than $n$ and coprime to $\displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a}}$

Let $q(n)$ be the small prime verify $n+m < \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a}}$

Let $b_1$ be the prime that the gap $(b,b+m)$ is appear the first time in $\mathcal{B}_{b_1}$ and $s = \#\{(b,b+m)\in\mathcal{B}_{b_1}^2\}$

I proove that $I_{q(n),m}(n) \sim \; 2 \, C_2 \, \theta_m \; \dfrac{n}{\ln(\ln(n))^2} e^{-2 \gamma}$

With $\theta_m$ is a constante verify $\dfrac{s}{\displaystyle {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \leq b_1 \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}} \leq \theta_m \leq \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$ , and $C_2 = \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a (a-2)}{(a-1)^2}} \right)}$

We have $\theta_2 = \theta_4 = 1$

If we denote $I_n$ the number of elements less than $n$ and coprime to $\displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$ ($q(n)$ the small prime verify $n < \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$)

I proove that $I_n \sim \dfrac{n}{\ln(\ln(n))} \, e^{-\gamma}$

We have : $\dfrac{n}{\ln(\ln(n))} \, e^{-\gamma} = \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)} \dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(\ln(n))} \, e^{-\gamma} \sim \pi(n) \big( \pi(q(n)) e^{-\gamma} \big)$

Let $\lambda_m(n) = \#\{p_{k+1}-p_k=m \, , \, p_{k+1} \leq n\}$

Then if we use the same analogy with the case $I_{q(n),m}(n)$ :

$I_{q(n), m}(n) \sim \lambda_m(n) \big( \pi(q(n)) \, e^{- \gamma} \big)^2$

Then : $\lambda_m(n) \sim \; 2 \, C_2 \, \theta_m \; \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)^2}$

Well that's just a conjecture (i don't proove $I_{q(n), m}(n) \sim \lambda_m(n) \big( \pi(q(n)) \, e^{- \gamma} \big)^2$)

We can also concluse the same thing about Hardy-Littlewood conjecture $\pi_m(n) \sim \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)} 2 \, C_2 \; \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)^2}$

**EDITED**

---

i fixe the confusion between $\lambda_m(n)$ and $\pi_m(n)$

---

http://lagrida.com/prime_numbers_construction.html

http://lagrida.com/Calculate_Gaps_Cardinality.html

http://lagrida.com/Fondamentale_Conjonctures_Prime_Numbers.html

Comment: The proof is in my article,
And show that we can't use Chinese remainder theorem to proof that !

because that true there is $p_i - 2$ elements verify (b,b+2) coprime to $p_i$.

But if we choose a couple $(b,b+2)$ coprime to $p_i$ then $(b,b+2)$ not necesserly both coprime to $p_j$

And the case $(b,b+6)$ is a greate example.

Comment: There is a lot of steps (i use notations in my article) :

1) $\mathcal{A}_q = \mathcal{B}_q \cup \mathcal{C}_q \, \text{ and } \, \mathcal{B}_q = \mathcal{A}_q \smallsetminus \mathcal{C}_q$ (property 14)

Comment: 2) $\displaystyle\forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-1)}}\} \, \exists ! t \in \{0,1,\cdots,q-1\} \, \exists ! k \in \{1,2,\cdots,{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-1)}}\} \quad q \, \beta_p(k) = {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)} t + \beta_p(i)$ (Property 18) 
 and i use a recursif formula.

Comment: My method can give cardinality of $(b,b+2m)$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$

Comment: that's why i used it.. the case $(b,b+6)$, $(b,b+8)$... become hard and hard

Comment: $\#\{(b,b+6) \in \mathcal{B}_q^2\} = 2 \text{ if } q = 5$

Comment: and if $q \geq 7$ let $b$ be the next prime to $p'$ then : $\displaystyle\#\{(b,b+6) \in \mathcal{B}_q^2\} = 2 \left( {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{7 \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} + {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{5 \leq a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-3)} \right)} + \sum_{\substack{5 \leq b' < p \\ \text{b' prime}}} {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{5 \leq a \leq b' \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-3)} \right)} {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{b < a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} \right)$

Comment: And for that reason the constants in first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture are false for $m \geq 6$

Comment: Show that $q$ is the next prime to $p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let $N_k = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$. The CRT says
  $$\mathbb{Z}/N_k \mathbb{Z} \cong \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}$$

  direct product of finite rings.

  Proof : for each $i$ there is $e_i\bmod N_k$, $e_i \equiv 1 \bmod p_i, (j \ne i), e_i \equiv 0 \bmod p_j$ so the isomorphism is $$n = \sum_{i=1}^k e_i n_i \in \mathbb{Z}/N_k \mathbb{Z} , \qquad n_i = n \in \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}$$
- Whence $$n +m= \sum_{i=1}^k e_i (n_i +m)\in \mathbb{Z}/N_k \mathbb{Z} , \qquad n_i+m = n+m \in \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}$$
- Let $1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if } gcd(n,N_k)=1 \\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$.

  Then

$$\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1} =
\sum_{(n_i) \in \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}} 1_{gcd(\sum_{i=1}^k e_i n_i,N_k)=1}1_{gcd(\sum_{i=1}^k e_i (n_i+m),N_k)=1}$$ $$ =\sum_{(n_i) \in \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}} \prod_{i=1}^k 1_{gcd(n_i,p_i)=1}1_{gcd( n_i+m,p_i)=1}=\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{n_i \in  \mathbb{Z}/p_i \mathbb{Z}} 1_{gcd(n_i,p_i)=1}1_{gcd( n_i+m,p_i)=1}$$
$$ = \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1) \tag{1}$$

- Since you are letting $k \to \infty$, why do you care of $\sum_{n \le N_k - m} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$ when $\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$ is much easier ?
- The twin prime counting function is $$\pi_2(k^2) = \sum_{n \le \color{red}{k^2}} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+2,N_k)=1}$$ and $(1)$ gives no clue about that.
- Let $N$ square-free. The same idea works for $$\sum_{n \bmod N} 1_{gcd(n,N)=gcd(n+m_1,N)=gcd(n+m_2,N)=1} = \prod_{p | N}\sum_{n \bmod p} 1_{gcd(n,p)=gcd(n+m_1,p)=gcd(n+m_2,p)=1}$$

  and $$\sum_{n \bmod N} \prod_{l=0}^L 1_{gcd(n+l,N)=1}  = \prod_{p | N}\sum_{n \bmod p} \prod_{l=0}^L 1_{gcd(n+l,p)=1} = \prod_{p | N} \max(0,p-L-1)\tag{2}$$
- Not sure why you'd wnt to do so, but you can also look at  $$\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=gcd(n+6,N_k)=1}\prod_{l=1}^5 1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)\ne 1} $$ $$ =\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=gcd(n+6,N_k)=1}\prod_{l=1}^5 (1-1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)= 1})$$ $$ = \sum_{m \in \{0,1\}^7,m_0=m_6=1} (-1)^{\sum_l m_l} f(N_k,m)$$
  where for $m \in \{0,1\}^{L+1}$, $f(N_k,m) = \sum_{n \bmod N_k} \prod_{l=0}^L (1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)=1})^{m_l}$. Since $2 | N_k$ then $f(N_k,m) \ne 0$ for only $3$ values of $m$ : $f(N_k,(1,0,0,0,0,0,1)) = 2\prod_{i=3}^k (p_i-2)$,$ f(N_k,(1,0,1,0,0,0,1)) = f(N_k,(1,0,0,0,1,0,1))=\prod_{i=3}^k (p_i-3)$ so that

$$\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=gcd(n+6,N_k)=1}\prod_{l=1}^5 1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)\ne 1} =2\prod_{i=3}^k (p_i-2)-2 \prod_{i=3}^k (p_i-3) \tag{3}$$

Comment: @Lagrida : I made the formalism simple and I proved you can't obtain anything non-trivial from $\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$, which is what most of your posts are about. If you think you have an argument to evaluate $\sum_{n \le x} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$ and if you want some help then show us how, in 3 lines, as I did (sploiler : the best estimate for $\sum_{n \le k^2} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$ is the Brun sieve, which is known to be optimal in some sense)

Comment: with my methode i get the close formula of cardinality $(b,b+m)$ and equal to : $s \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} + \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} E_{p,k} \right) + \sum_{\substack{b_1 \leq \alpha_1 < p \\ \alpha_1\text{ prime}}} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} E_{\alpha_1,k} \right) {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{\alpha < a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}$
with $b$ is the next prime to $b_1$, $\alpha$ the next prime to $\alpha_1$ and $s$ the cardinale at $\mathcal{B}_{b_1}$ and $q$ is the next prime to $p$

Comment: I don't care of your result, I'm asking your argument

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: @LAGRIDA $N_k = \prod_{i\le k} p_i$. Once you know $\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1} 
= \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)$ (and the equivalent formulas for $\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m_1,N_k)=1}1_{gcd(n+m_2,N_k)=1} $) what do you want more, what are you looking at, how do you obtain more (useful) results. Are you looking at $\sum_{n \le x} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$, for what $x,m$, and how do you get something useful.

Comment: I use this inequality to get results: $s \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} \leq \#\{(b,b+m)\in\mathcal{B}_q^2\} \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)} {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}$

Comment: the right terme is evidant (Chinese remainder theorem) but not equal $\#\{(b,b+m)\in\mathcal{B}_q^2\}$ when $m \geq 6$

Comment: Then i conjucture that : $\displaystyle\#\{(p,p+m)\in\mathbb{P}^2\, , \, p+m \leq n\} \sim 2 \theta_m \; C_2 \; \dfrac{n}{\ln^2(n)}$ with $\displaystyle \frac{s}{\displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \leq b_1 \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}} \leq \theta_m \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$

Comment: If $m \geq 6$ the inequality of $\theta_m$ is strict.

Comment: You are supposed to use my notations... I explained in my answer why (with $k = \pi(q) $) your $\#\{(b,b+m)\in\mathcal{B}_q^2\}  = \sum_{n \le N_k-m} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}$ introduces unnecessary messy terms. $\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}  = \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)$. It means $\sum_{n \le x} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1} = x \frac{\prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)}{N_k}+O(N_k)$ so it is useless for $x = k^2, k \to \infty$. Then what ?

Comment: This equality is false : $\displaystyle\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}  = \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)$

Comment: you can verify that in case $m=6$ and $q=13$

Comment: Create a programme and test this case, the values of elements less than primorial 13 and coprime to primorial 13 : http://lagrida.com/primorial_13.txt

Comment: For $m \geq 6$ we have : $\displaystyle\sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}  < \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)$

Comment: @LAGRIDA No that's $=$ for $k=6,N_k = \prod_{p \le 13} p, m=6$ and for every $k,m$, look again at your program. That's the point of replacing your $\sum_{n \le N_k-m}$ by $\sum_{n \le N_k} = \sum_{n \bmod N_k}$ where the CRT gives a product over the $p_i$

Comment: well the programm give 1690 elements (b,b+6) less than primorial 13 and coprime to primorial 13

Comment: And $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1, p_i \,\nmid\, m}^k(p_i-2)\prod_{l=1, p_l\, |\, m}^k(p_l-1)$ give 2970

Comment: My Prooved formula $\displaystyle\#\{(b,b+6) \in \mathcal{B}_q^2\} = 2 \left( {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{7 \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} + {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{5 \leq a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-3)} \right)} + \sum_{\substack{5 \leq b' < p \\ \text{b' prime}}} {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{5 \leq a \leq b' \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-3)} \right)} {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{b < a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} \right)$ give exactly $1690$

Comment: Yes $2970 = \sum_{n \le N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=1} 1_{gcd(n+6,N_k)=1} $, where $N_k = 30030 = \prod_{p \le 13} p$

Comment: It's only $1690$ elements $(b,b+6)$ coprime to primorial 13 and less primorial 13

Comment: Hard to do a mistake when looking at `Nk = 30030; s= 0; for n=1:Nk, s = s+(gcd(n,Nk)==1)*(gcd(n+6,Nk)==1); end;`

Comment: create gcd function and determine all elements less than primorial 13 in a file then put them in array and verify b[i+1]-b[i]=6

Comment: @LAGRIDA Please type in https://octave-online.net/  `Nk = 30030; s= 0; for n=1:Nk, s = s+(gcd(n,Nk)==1)*(gcd(n+6,Nk)==1); end; s` and `Nk = prod(primes(13))`

Comment: Can you give me the liste of elements less than primorial 13 and coprime to 13 ?

Comment: I reteste my programme and he work very will, let work in a C programm

Comment: Your programm is wrong, consider this programm in C language :
 int i, n = 30030; FILE* fichier = fopen("test.txt", "a+");for(i=1; i<=n; i++){ if(gcd(n, i) == 1){ fprintf(fichier,",%d",i); } }

Comment: After you copy elements from test.txt and put it in table T[]={1,17,...}; Write this : 
for(i=0; i<5759; i++){ if(T[i+1] - T[i] == 6){ s++; } } printf("%d\n",s);

Comment: Your programm give a kill error is that we search for consecutif (b,b+6) coprime to primorial 13 and not b,b+6 coprime to primorial 13

Comment: The value $2970$ is true if b,b+6 coprime to primorial 13 but we search for consecutif (b,b+6) to primorial 13

Comment: @LAGRIDA I added at the end of my answer the formula you are asking. Please type `L = 6; P = [11,13,19]; N = prod(P); s = 0; for n=1:N, s = s + prod( (gcd(n+(0:L),N)==1) ); end; t = prod( max(P-L-1,0)); s-t` in octave online (the prime factors of $N$ must be larger than $L+1$ for the result being non-zero)

Comment: We calculate the cardinal of differente sets, for elements less than primorial 13 and coprime to primorial 13 :
I give the cardinale of {(23,29), (31,37), ...}
And you give the cardinale of {(17,23), (23,29),...}

Comment: I calculate the cardinale of consecutif elements (b,b+m) less than primorial q and coprime to primorial q, this cardinal is less than cardinal given by C.R.T

Comment: Thanks Mr @reuns, the last formule in your insere say that C.R.T is not able to get the cardinality for $m \geq 6$ of consecutif elements $(b,b+m)$ in $\mathcal{B}_q$ and the reason is clear that C.R.T is used only for unique variable, we can only proof that $\#\mathcal{B}_q = \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-1)} \right)}$ but for $(b,b+m)$ or $(b,b+m,b+n)$ ... we should use other method to calculate cardinality of consecutif numbers ..

Comment: The correct code for consecutif b,b+6 : Nk = 30030; s= 0; for n=1:Nk, s = s+(gcd(n,Nk)==1)*(gcd(n+6,Nk)==1)*prod( (gcd(n+(1:5),Nk)!=1) ); end; s

Comment: @LAGRIDA Please make some efforts. Your last code means $ \sum_{n \bmod N} 1_{gcd(n,N)=gcd(n+6,N)=1} \prod_{l=1}^5 1_{gcd(n+l,N)\ne 1}$. Why would you want to look at that ? Anyway $1_{gcd(n+l,N)\ne 1} = 1-1_{gcd(n+l,N)= 1}$ so expand $  \prod_{l=1}^5 (1-1_{gcd(n+l,N)= 1})$ and use the formulas in my answer. You'll get a sum of $2^5 = 32$ products over the primes, and with $N=N_k$ most of them will be zero.

Comment: (with $2 | N$ only $3$ won't be zero, see my answer) `  P = primes(13); Nk = prod(P); s = 0; for n=1:Nk, s = s + (gcd(n,Nk)==1)*(gcd(n+6,Nk)==1)*prod( (gcd(n+(1:5),Nk)!=1) ); end;  t = 2*prod(P(3:end)-2)-2*prod(P(3:end)-3); s-t  ` @LAGRIDA

Comment: Thanks Mr reuns that's true, i understand the case m=6, in generale if $m \geq 8$ we have $\theta_m = \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$ ? you have right

Comment: Explain "most of them be zero" and how that can influence $\theta_m$, if $\theta_m = \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$ that mean $\theta_m$ is independent of first time the gap $(b,b+m)$ appear.

Comment: @LAGRIDA Please make some efforts, use my notations, make clear what you understand and what you don't... $f(N_k,(1,1,0,0,0,0,1)) = 0$ because $2 | N_k$ implies $1_{gcd(n,N_k)}1_{gcd(n+1,N_k)=1} = 0$. Then what ?

Comment: Yes you have right, $(1,0,1,0,0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0,0,1,0,1)$ represent gaps $(b,b+2,b+6)$ and $(b,b+4,b+6)$

Comment: My question is the value of terme $\alpha$ where : $\displaystyle\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}\prod_{l=1}^{m-1} 1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)\ne 1} =\alpha \prod_{i=t}^k (p_i-2)+ \cdots$

Comment: @LAGRIDA For $k > t = \pi(m), u \in \{0,1\}^{m+1}$ and $d = \sum_{j=0}^m u_j$ then $f(N_k,u) = f(N_t,u) \prod_{i=t+1}^k (p_i-d)$. So once $m$ is fixed you can precompute the $\alpha_{m,d}$ such that $\sum_{n \bmod N_k} 1_{gcd(n,N_k)=gcd(n+m,N_k)=1}\prod_{l=1}^{m-1} 1_{gcd(n+l,N_k)\ne 1} =  \sum_{d=2}^m \alpha_{m,d} \prod_{i=t}^k (p_i-d)$. But you didn't explain yet why you'd want to look at those things. $\alpha_{m,2} = f(N_t,(1,0,\ldots,0,1))$ and the sum is $\sim \alpha_{m,2}\prod_{i=t+1}^k (p_i-2)$ as $k \to \infty$ (then use the PNT and Mertens theorems)

Comment: Because the reel constantes verify the conjecture $\pi_m(n) \sim 2 \theta_m \, C_2 \frac{n}{\ln(n)^2}$ is for $\displaystyle \frac{s}{\displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \leq b_1 \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}} \leq \theta_m \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$ and not $\theta_m = \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$

Comment: with $b_1$ the first prime number whene the gap $(b,b+m)$ is appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_{b_1}$ and $s = \#\{(b,b+m) \in \mathcal{B}_{b_1}^2 \}$

Comment: Examples: The gap $(b,b+6)$ appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_5$ and $s=2$, The gap $(b,b+8)$ appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_7$ and $s=2$, The gap $(b,b+10)$ appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_7$ and $s=2$, The gap $(b,b+12)$ appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_{11}$ and $s=8$...

Comment: The gap $(b,b+16)$ appear the first time at $\mathcal{B}_{13}$ and $s=12$

Comment: The method you use is better than my method, the formula i found for number of consecutif elements $(b,b+m)$ in $\mathcal{B}_q$ is : $s \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)} + \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} E_{p,k} \right) + \sum_{\substack{b_1 \leq \alpha_1 < p \\ \alpha_1\text{ prime}}} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} E_{\alpha_1,k} \right) {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{\alpha < a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}$.

Comment: This formula give only the inequality $\displaystyle \frac{s}{\displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{3 \leq a \leq b_1 \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-2)} \right)}} \leq \theta_m \leq {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)}$, but your method can give the exacte formula of $\theta_m$ : $\theta_m = \dfrac{\alpha_{m,2}}{\displaystyle {\small \prod_{i=2}^{t} {\normalsize (p_i-2)}}}$

Comment: Mr reuns you have an idea why $I_{q(n), m}(n) \sim \pi_m(n) \big( \pi(q(n)) \, e^{- \gamma} \big)^2$ ? with $I_{q(n), m}(n)$ denote the number of consecutif elements $(b,b+m)$ less than $n$ and coprime to $\displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq q(n) \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a}}$

Comment: Mr @reuns i edit the topic, i have a confusion between $\pi_m(n)$ and $\lambda_m(n) = \#\{p_{k+1}-p_k=m \, , \, p_{k+1} \leq n\}$, my conjecture is about $\lambda_m(n) \sim \; 2 \, C_2 \, \theta_m \; \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)^2}$, and my work also give the conjecture $\pi_m(n) \sim \displaystyle{\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a | m \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize \frac{a-1}{a-2}} \right)} 2 \, C_2 \; \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)^2}$ and all of those things are true if we discover the way to the missing proove $I_n \sim \pi(n) \big( \pi(q(n)) e^{-\gamma} \big) \sim \pi(n) \big( \pi(p(n)) e^{-\gamma} \big)$

Answer (score 0):

You should use more common notations for readability, especially when your variables are changing all the time ($t$ becomes $\alpha$, $b$ becomes $\beta_p(i)$ then $\beta$, $\alpha$ becomes $t$ again $b$ is not $b$ anymore, $\alpha$ becomes something else again...)

$I_{p_a}(n)=\phi(n,a)$ ([Legendre formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html))

$u_q(n)=\phi(\frac{n}{p_{a+1}},a)$

$\mathcal{B}_q = \mathcal{A}_q \smallsetminus \mathcal{C}_q$ is equivalent to $\phi(n,a)=\phi(n,a-1)-\phi(\frac{n}{p_a},a-1)$

$$I_p(n) = {\small \left( \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize (a-1)} \right)} \, \left\lfloor \frac{n}{\displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a}}} \right\rfloor + I_p(\beta)$$

is just 
$$\phi(s\cdot m_k + t,k)=s\cdot \varphi(m_k)+\phi(t,k)$$

with ${\small \big( \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ a\text{ prime}}} {\normalsize a} \big)}=p_a\#=m_k$

${\small \big( \prod_{\substack{a \leq p \\ a\text{ prime}}} {\normalsize (a-1)} \big)}=\varphi(p_a\#)=\varphi(m_k)$

$s = \alpha$ and $t = \beta$

Also, your gaps formulas are only valid for sieves up to $p\#$.

Anyway, on your third link, your first formula you set $K_a$ with a formula only valid at $\infty$. Because of that, things go wrong when you start mixing $K_a$ and $K_b$

Comment: No Mr.Collag3n ! $K_b = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{a < b \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\frac{1}{a}}\right)}$ with $b$ is a finite number ($b$ is the first prime verfy the gap $g$ appear the first time in $\mathcal{B}_b$)

Comment: You confuse with : $F_b(x) = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{b \leq a \\ \text{a prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\right)}$